# Oracle SUM Values based on multiple Timestamps

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I got some problem where I can't really wrap my head around.

I have a table with timestamps for ventilation duration which contains the whole duration of different episodes in minutes where the patient was ventilated and some other data + a key to with the patient's case ID.

Here is an example of the table:

| PK | CaseID | Duration | Begin | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 45860 | 2018-01-13 12:15:00 | 2018-02-14 08:35:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 132 | 2018-01-11 11:45:00 | 2018-01-13 12:15:00 |

So as you see one case can have multiple rows in this table.
Now in another table I have the departments and stations where the patient / case was during their stay in hospital (from admission to discharge) - also with timestamps:

| PK | CaseID | Begin | End | StationID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2018-01-13 11:53:00 | 2018-01-13 12:11:00 | 123 |
| 2 | 1 | 2018-01-13 12:11:00 | 2018-02-18 10:59:00 | 123 |
| 3 | 1 | 2018-02-25 09:15:00 | 2018-02-26 11:27:00 | 123 |
| 4 | 1 | 2018-02-26 11:27:00 | 2018-03-01 10:04:00 | 123 |
| 5 | 1 | 2018-03-01 11:06:00 | 2018-03-03 14:25:00 | 234 |

Now I'd like to build a query to sum up the ventilation duration on specific stations. As you can see I don't have a station reference in the first table, so I have to compare the timestamps to get the time when we was on this specific station (for example - like here - with ID 123).

I think I get the logic that the beginning of the ventilation must be more than or equal to the beginning of the station's visit and the end has to be less than or equal to the end of the station's visit, but I'm not sure how to deal with those multiple stays (e.g. when re-admissioned).

I came up with the following query which seems to work but the numbers are a bit on the lower side in my opinion:

```
@set start_date = '01.01.2018 00:00:00'
@set end_date = '31.08.2021 23:59:59'
@set format = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

SELECT 
    "Year",
    SUM("Ventilation Duration") AS "Sum"
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        f.CASEID AS "FallID",
        SUM(DECODE(fb.DURATION, 20 , ROUND(fb.DURATION / 60, 0), 21, fb.DURATION)) AS "Ventilation Duration",
        TO_CHAR(fa.BEGIN, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS "Begin Station Stay",
        TO_CHAR(fb.BEGIN, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS "Begin Ventilation",
        TO_CHAR(fb.END, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS "End Ventilation",
        TO_CHAR(fa.END, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS "End Station Stay",
        oe.STATION_NAME AS "Station",
        TO_CHAR(f.DISCHARGE_DATE, 'YYYY') AS "YEAR"
    FROM 
        CASE_VENTLATION fb
    INNER JOIN 
        CASE_STAY fa ON fa.CASEID = fb.CASEID
    INNER JOIN 
        CASE f ON f.CASEID = fb.CASEID 
    INNER JOIN 
        STATION oe ON oe.STATIONID = fa.STATIONID
    WHERE 
        f.STORNO_DATUM IS NULL 
        AND f.DISCHARGE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:start_date, :format) AND TO_DATE(:end_date, :format)
        AND fa.STATIONID = 10097
        AND f.CASEMARK IN (38140, 38142)
        AND fb.BEGIN >=(SELECT MIN(fa.BEGIN)FROM CASE_STAY fa2 WHERE fa2.CASEID = fb.CASEID AND fa2.STATION_ID = fa.STATION_ID)
        AND fb.END <= SELECT MAX(fa.ENDE)FROM CASE_STAY fa2 WHERE fa2.CASEID = fb.CASEID AND  fa2.STATION_ID = fa.STATION_ID)
    GROUP BY
        ...
    )
GROUP BY "Year"
ORDER BY "Year"
```

Would you consider this als logically correct or can I write a better WHERE-Condition - especially with the MIN and MAX functions.

Don't mind the aliases, I translated some field names from German so it's easier to understand to what fields in the example they refer.

**EDIT: As requested, this is my current result:**

| Year | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2018 | 23412 |
| 2019 | 35618 |
| 2020 | 25633 |
| 2021 | 19682 |

Problem is, as I said, it's a bit on the lower side and I guess I missed some due to those timestamp overlaps :/.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: are you really using oracle ? what are those set ? It looks to me like sql server

Comment: I use Oracle with DBeaver as DBMS. The @set let's you define variables you can use in your statements so you don't have to define them over and over if you have subqueries or many UNION statements for example.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I was asking because it looked like sql variables in TSQL of SQL Server

Comment: Why can't you just use the `CaseID` for this?  Isn't `CaseID` tied to a specific patient? The storage of the various timestamps, that may or may not overlap for the expected patient, may be a design problem.  What will you do with time ranges that do not overlap with the rows in the first table?

Comment: Hi Max, guten Tag. Can you please update the query with results you exoect from that test data?

Comment: I did - indeed I GET a result from my query but I don't think that it covers all hours of ventilation.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I joined them using the ID but the problem is that the patient could be ventilated on another station aswell. That's why I need to do it with the timestamps I guess. Yeah the design is not the best, unfortunately I can't change it.

Comment: Your current result has no `per station` detail in the result.  Wasn't that a requirement?  I'm a little confused with your request.  You showed no `per station` current results.  If you don't need `per station` detail, then why do you need to care about the timestamp overlap?  Just sum up all the rows matching the `CaseID` and `GROUP BY` anything you wish (like year).  But you might need to logically split some entries that span the ranges related to the required groups.  Your SQL contains `...`.  It should be complete and  expected results exact based on the test data you showed.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I'm specifying the station's ID in the WHERE-Clause, so I only evaulate one specific station with this query (Where ... AND fa.STATIONID = 10097). That's why I dont't have thix extra column in my result.

Comment: That's fine.  But you don't need to check timestamp overlap if we have a `CaseID`.  We know which rows to use based on `CaseID`, correct?  I must be missing something about the use of `CaseID`.

Comment: I'll try to explain it: The CASEID is in both tables, yes. If I join table 1 and table 2 from the example I get all records with all stations where the patient was during his stay. But now I need to figure out which times MATCH (I know there could be a bit of overlap) so I know that during the time from X to Y, the patient was on station with ID 123. If I just use the case ID and he was also ventilated on station 234 or other stations it's a false result.

Comment: To clarify this, maybe the above test case needs to be completed.  Provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements, with `INSERT` statements to provide specific test data.  Then show the actual query you used against this test data.  Provide the actual result and the _precise_ expected result, based on this specific test data.  Just the minimum required for the test.  Feel free to remove everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I am not completely sure whether I got the task correctly but it seems to be interesting, so I'll try. Sorry if I'm wrong.

If all you need is to calculate amount of minutes patients were ventilated on each station, here is what I have:

```
select st.station_id, 
      v.caseid,
      sum((least(v.end_date, st.end_date) - greatest(v.begin_date, st.begin_date)) * 24 * 60) vent_duration_mins
 from vent v
 join dep_stat st
   on v.caseid = st.caseid
  and v.begin_date < st.end_date 
  and v.end_date > st.begin_date
group by st.station_id,          
         v.caseid
```

This case assumes all date columns are of date type, not timestamp

[db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=695707e1cab60d04ee05e20d9266f382)

Comment: This seems quite logical I didn't thought about least and greatest. I'll try it out next week when I get back to work :). Maybe I just overcomplicated things cause I spent a few hours on that problem. Anyway thanks for your Help! May be I csn get a fiddle working later aswell.

Comment: Kein Problem. Let me know if did help or not

Comment: Hab's mal auf dem Homeoffice Laptop probiert, scheint zu funktionieren! Kannst du  mir noch erklären wie du auf das LEAST und GREATEST kamst? Danke nochmal! :)

Comment: @Max I'll continue in English. I can German too but we are in English version of the community. The LEAST takes the least parameter from the list of parameters given. And since we need to take the minimumal date from ventilation end date or a date when patient is no longer in the hospital, that was the right way to use this function. Same thing for the greatest. It makes the opposite: it takes the greatest value from the parameters given.

Comment: Yeah I read the Oracle docs about those functions but your explanation makes Sense. I reworked the query a bit for my needs and it seems to give the right values. So Thanks again you saved the rest of my week :D